# Is it possible to read any particular data directly from a file?

Tags: c, file, pointers

Is it possible to read any particular data directly from a file without reading line by line or character by character or block by block ?

I have stored name, roll, marks and passing year of few students in file.
Below is the contents of file..

```
suraj
1
411
2020
john
3
400
2005
aman raj
5
389
2015
```

I want to print only passing year of a student name `john`.
Below is my code..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char name[20];
    int roll;
    int total_marks;
    int passing_year;

    FILE *ptr;
    ptr = fopen("/storage/testing.txt", "r");
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        perror("File not found");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while (feof(ptr) == 0)
    {
        fgets(name, 20, ptr); // *Edit: The 2nd argument will less or equal to 20. 
        fscanf(ptr, "%d\n", &roll);//line 1
        fscanf(ptr, "%d\n", &total_marks);//line 2
        fscanf(ptr, "%d\n", &passing_year);//line 3

        if (strcmp(name, "john\n") == 0) //\n because fgets() add newline before \0 (only if size specified is more than no. of characters)
            printf("passing year of John was %d\n", passing_year);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program runs successfully. Below is the result from console..

```
passing year of John was 2005

[Program finished]
```

Here, I require only `passing year of john` but I have to read the whole file. Of course, I can change pointing position by `fseek()` but then also I have to read minimum line 1, line 2 and line 3.
I want to know that, is there any way by which we can read the particular data directly from the file as we used in case of variables in console I/O (temporary storage)?
why can't we access data from file similarly as console(using variables) ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236455/discussion-on-question-by-suraj-is-it-possible-to-read-any-particular-data-direc).

Comment: @BhargavRao Many of those comments were hints and even partial answers to the OP.  I would not have called them "extended discussion", and I wish you hadn't moved them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each student occupies the same space in file (and the file is, possibly, no longer a *text file*) you can `fseek()` to any specific index

```
suraj    |  1 | 411 | 2020\n           // 27 bytes per student
john     |  3 | 400 | 2005\n           // still a text file
aman raj |  5 | 389 | 2015\n           // uses more space than a
pmg      | 42 |  87 | 2000\n           // more efficient format
```

---

```
fseek(studentfile, 27 * 2, SEEK_SET);
fgets(buffer, 28, studentfile); // read aman raj data
```

Comment: Thanks. I unable to understand why displacement = `27 * 2` ? Is is same that each student takes 27 bytrs, so For 3rd student , we skipped 2 students i.e 2*27 =54 bytes ?

Comment: And one more question I have to ask. If We don't know the real exact position or taking `name` from user (from console) then there is no option. We have to search line by line using the condition. Am I right ?

Comment: Right on both questions. What you can do is assign a number to each student, and then `fseek` to that number (possibly `- 1`) instead. And do consider using a proper database for large data sets :-)

Comment: I prefer tab (ASCII code 9 or `\t`) for separator - instead of `|` in this example. It does not reserve useful chars like `|`.

Comment: @i486: _I prefer tab_ --> yes.

Comment: In reality, all those `|` (or tabs) and most spaces are redundant and can be omited in a fixed-width format. They help with manual (human) editing.

Comment: @Suraj If you need efficient lookup of records (perhaps in terms of record number) by name, you will typically use a separate index.  If that index is sorted (and especially if *it* has fixed-size records), you can search in it efficiently using techniques like *binary search*.  Or you can use a *hash table*.  And if you want, that separate index can give you fseek offsets into your main database, meaning that your main database doesn't have to use fixed-size records, after all.

Comment: @SteveSummit: Thanks.  _separate index can give you fseek offsets into your main database_  Please explain this point.

Comment: @Suraj Too complicated to explain in a comment; see partial answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1):

[partial, incomplete answer]

It can be useful to use a separate index — perhaps in a separate file — to enable efficient lookup and seeking into your main database.  For example, consider this file:

```
aman raj   33
john       17
suraj      0
```

It's in alphabetical order by name, so you can theoretically use *binary search* in it.  The second column gives you a number you can hand to `fseek` to jump directly to the desired record in the main data file you initially presented in your question (using `fseek` calls as described elsewhere).

(Although you can't see it, I'm imagining that the two columns in this file are separated by a single tab character, so that there won't be any ambiguity involving spaces in names like `aman raj`.)

Alternatively, here is an index into the data file in @pmg's answer.  In this index, the number in the second column is a record number, not a raw `fseek` offset.  (That is, the number in the second column is the number which must be multiplied by 27 to get the fseek offset in pmg's code.)

```
aman raj   2
john       1
pmg        3
suraj      0
```

Another likely possibility, which is more involved to illustrate so I'm not going to do that here yet, is a *hash table*.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.

Comment: Here indexing helps to identify the position but it will work only if each student is taking same bytes (here 27 bytes so we use _index no. * 27_ for `fseek()` offset.)

Comment: Ok, I will try it using binary search.

Comment: @Suraj to clarify, the index can either yield numbers which need to be multiplied by the size of fixed-size records, *or* it can directly give fseek offsets into a file which does not use fixed-size records.  I illustrated both possibilities.

Comment: Okay Got it. Thanks again.